# nginx get origin client ip from x-forwarded for using map module

Tags: nginx, x-forwarded-for

Ip have request flows through 3 nginx proxy, and ip got the  x-forwarded-for list ip of :

```
192.168.10.222, 192.168.10.178, 192.168.10.179
```

how can I get the first ip using map module ?
I've found this but can't make it working:

```
map $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for $client_ip {

"~(?<IP>([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}),.*" $IP;

}
```

from here: https://webkul.com/blog/x-forwarded-for-header-in-nginx-containing-mulitple-client-ips

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to read x-forwared-for or you want to write x-forwared-for with the client ip ?

Comment: @flaixman currently read is enough

Comment: that example is only for ipv4

Answer (score 2):

Thats what you are looking for:

```
map $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for $client_ip {"~(?<IP>([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}),.*" $IP;}
```

It will map the first ip of the 3 to the variable $client_ip.
As one line out of the server and location scope.

Comment: this is only for ipv4

Answer (score 1):

find a more clear way:

```
map $http_x_forwarded_for $real_ip {
    ~^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) $1;
    default $remote_addr;
}
```

Then we can use the new variable `$real_ip` in `geo` command:

```
geo $real_ip $backend {
    default upstream-default;
    1.1.1.1 upstream-backend001;
    2.2.2.2 upstream-backend002;
}
```

or overwrite default log-format (replace `$remote_addr` with `$real_ip`)：

```
    #log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    log_format main '$real_ip - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                    '"$request" $http_host $status $request_length $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$uri" "$args" "$request_time" "$upstream_addr" '
                    '"$upstream_response_time" "$http_user_agent"';
```

Comment: Only works for ipv4, not ipv6